# Emulator won't start in Mac OS 10.11.16 required Mac OS 10.12 or later

Tags: macos, android-studio

Emulator: Sorry, "qemu-system-armel" can not be run on this version of macOS. Qt requires macOS 10.12.0 or later, you have macOS 10.11.6.

Comment: What part of that message is unclear?

Comment: i need to know if exist a way to use android emulator on my Mac OS 10.11.16

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Mac OS X El Capitan (Version 10.11.6), so I couldn't run the latest emulator versions (version 29.0.9 is the latest available as of today).

I had to downgrade to the [Android Emulator Version 28.0.25](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-5395263.zip).

Comment: what I do with files now?